# I want to Redirect the user to appropriate Error page based on the type of Exception

Tags: asp.net, exception, model-view-controller, try-catch

I want to Redirect the user to appropriate error page based on the type of `Exception`. How do I get the type of `Exception` occurred in any action method while overloading `OnException` method of `HandleErrorAttribute` class. How do I display respective message to the user based on exception occurred.

```
public class CustomErrorAttribute:HandleErrorAttribute
  {

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
      string data = "\n" + filterContext.Exception.StackTrace;
      if(HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError().GetType()== typeof(ArithmeticException))
      {
          Log(data);
          filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
          View = "ErrorView2";
      }
      else if(HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError().GetType() == typeof(ArgumentOutOfRangeException))
      {
          Log(data);
          filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
          View = "ErrorView";
      }
      //filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Shared/ErrorView.cshtml");
    }
    void Log(string data)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Data/Log.txt"), data);
    }

  }
```

The method from which I am throwing the error is as follows:

```
    public string test(int no)
    {
       if(no<10)
       {
          return "No Exception";
       }
       else
       {
          throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
       }
    }
    public string test2(int no)
    {
       if (no < 10)
       {
          return "No Exception";
       }
       else
       {
          throw new ArithmeticException();
       }
    }
```

Comment: Is your project ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: @Win asp.net mvc

Comment: I want the answer to that too..not exaclty redirect to diffrent Page but to show in the alert ...but anyway nice question

Comment: Where is your code?  What have you tried?

Comment: @Mister Positve ......Plz refer the above code and suggest the solution. thank you